# AWS ECS Periodical Job - Automatically Scale in instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-ecs

Amazon ECS provides really good service for scheduled tasks : [ECS Scheduled tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html) that works pretty well.
However it's important in this always keep one ECS instance in ECS cluster.
What is the best way:

1. Launch/scale in ECS instance in for periodical job (just before task execution);
2. Run ECS tasks on newly created instance;
3. Terminate/scale out instance after completion.

One possible workaround is to write lambda that will do smth. like that ([launch ec2](https://medium.com/tomincode/launching-ec2-instances-from-lambda-4a96f1264afb)) but it looks as too much pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out an easy solution for that problem. Everything was quite simple:

1. Go to Autoscaling groups (This you can find on EC2 dashboard-> Autoscaling section);
2. Create scheduled action (In that case necessary frequency can be specified for your container instance);
3. Save your configuration. Instance will be added in the specified time.
4. In my case I also need to scale down this instance in 1 hour period.